# Wet Rated Pot Light

Tags: shower, light, recessed-lighting

I moved into my house last year, the bathroom has pot lights and had a walk in tub. We are now installing a shower and a pot light will be in the shower. Is there a way to tell if the pot light originally installed is wet rated? Located in Ontario

Answer (score 1):

Find a make/model number on the thing and look it up. Or, *possibly*, while looking for the make and model number, find a label that indicates it's wet-rated directly.

I suspect CEC and NEC are sufficiently similar that it will need to be GFCI-protected if in (or even close to) the shower.